# OpenVPN client for Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, openvpn

I've been trying to get the OpenVPN client to install on a Windows 7 laptop, and so far none of the various versions work. Some won't install at all (one version's `.exe` installer humorously told me that "OpenVPN is not supported on Windows"), other have problems during or after installation with a library (libeay32.dll I think).

I know that there are people who've successfully gotten it working, but I'm out of ideas. The versions I've tried are 2.0.9, 2.2 beta 3, 2.1.3, and a couple others. I think 2.0.9 gets farthest, but "tapinstall.exe" doesn't work (and gives no explanation of what happened; it just prints a message that it failed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenVPN 2.1.3 from [OpenVPN.net](http://www.openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html) installs and works fine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's one of the versions that gives me the errors about libeay32.dll.  The errors come up in the installer, and then if I "Ignore" it the client fails as soon as it tries to connect.

Comment: Is the Windows-7 installation on your laptop a "clean" one (format + reinstall, then install OpenVPN) or not? Could this be an indication of further problems with your Windows-7 system?

Comment: I think the Windows 7 installation's about as good as it can be. The DLL problem I've found was just a result of the installer failing to stop an old version of the OpenVPN GUI.  Once I killed that, install works, but I still can't get it to add more adapters, and the one the installer creates can connect to a VPN but then not do anything.  I tend to become enraged whenever I come in contact with Windows anyway; it was a whim project.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I uninstall previous versions of OpenVPN before installing a newer one. As to the adapter not passing any traffic though, maybe this is a configuration problem? If your config file contains a "dev tun0" try changing it to "dev tun".